# Replace partial view with ajax response data

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, spring, jsp

I have two views - `adminPage.jsp` and `studentForm.jsp`.

In `adminPage`, I have a button which allows a user to open a student from (get studentForm with ajax). User is able to enter student data in this form and then click the register button to add a student in database.

This operation is performed successfully, but I have one problem. Post request (request to add student in database) is called from `studentForm.jsp` and the result is received in it too. I want to replace an existing `studentForm` with a new one (response received after post request), but as a result, I get the whole page replaced with the `studentForm`.

What should I change?

This is adminPage, where I make get request and load the response in div element with id - viewContainer:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>

            function onk() {
                $.get({
                    url: "/student/studentForm",
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('#viewContainer').html(result);
                    }
                });
            }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h4>Username: ${user.username}</h4>

        <h1>heading 1</h1>
        <p> paragraph 1</p>
        <p> paragraph 2</p>

        <input type="button" id="userAddLoader" value="Add Student" onclick="onk();"/>

        <div id="viewContainer" style="background-color: red">
            <!-- this is container -->
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

this is `studentForm.jsp`:

```
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            $('#form1').onsubmit(function (e) {

                var form = $('#form1');

                $.post({
                        url: form.attr("action"),
                        data: form,
                        success: function (data) {
                            $('#viewContainer').html(data);
                        }
                    }
                );

                e.preventDefault(); //avoid to execute the actual submit of the form

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <c:set var="stat" scope="request" value="${status}"/>
        <c:if test="${stat == 'success'}">
            <script>
                alert("Student was successfully added");
            </script>
        </c:if>

        <h6>New Student Registration</h6>
        <form:form action="/student/postStudent" method="post" modelAttribute="user" id="form1">
            Username: <form:input type="text" path="username" id="username"/>
            Password: <form:input type="text" path="password" id="password"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Register">
        </form:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Check your servlet there may be a redirection defined. `onSubmit` is not a valid jquery event use `submit` instead.

Comment: submit seems to be deprecated and it doesn't submit form too.. I am using spring-boot with default configuration

Comment: Then submit the form using button click event listner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced this:

```
$('#form1').onsubmit(function (e) {

            var form = $('#form1');

            $.post({
                    url: form.attr("action"),
                    data: form,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#viewContainer').html(data);
                    }
                }
            );

            e.preventDefault(); //avoid to execute the actual submit of the form

        });
```

with this:

```
$('#form1').on("submit", function (e) {

            var form = $('#form1');

            $.post({
                    url: form.attr("action"),
                    data: form.serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#viewContainer').html(data);
                    }
                }
            );

            e.preventDefault();

        });
```

and problem was solved.

**Conclusion**:

1. `onSubmit` does not work in this case. Can be used `submit`, but newer approach as described in Jquery docs is `on("submit", function (e) ...`
2. form should be serialized  `form.serialize()`